# Imaginey and real part of Answer of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose  we have answer of homogeneous  differential equation that containing real and imaginary part. My question is that real part alone and imaginary part alone are answers of differential equation or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, in general. Say $y' = (1+i)y$. Then one solution is $y(t) = e^{(1+i)t} = e^t(\cos t+i\sin t)$. But $\text{Re}(y(t)) = e^t\cos t$ and $\text{Im}(y(t)) = e^t \sin t$ are not solutions.

In some (important) cases however, it does hold. In particular, if there are two linear independent solutions corresponding to a conjugate pair of roots of the characteristic function, the real and imaginary parts are solutions. E.g., if $y'' = y$, then $y_1(t) = e^{it}$ and $y_2 = e^{-it}$ are solutions such that $\text{Re}(y_1(t))$ and $\text{Im}(y_1(t))$ are also solutions.