# Is the real part of a complex solution to a linear differential equation always a solution? If so, why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the general solution $f(t)$ to a linear differential equation with real coefficients can be written as $$f(t)=a_1e^{A_1t}+a_2e^{A_2t}+a_3e^{A_3t}+...$$
Would $\text{Im}(f(t))$ and $\text{Re}(f(t))$ also be solutions?

That's the idea I'm getting from the following questions:

- [What is the meaning of having imaginary solutions to a differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856816/what-is-the-meaning-of-having-imaginary-solutions-to-a-differential-equation)
- [Imaginey and real part of Answer of differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282997/imaginey-and-real-part-of-answer-of-differential-equation)

although I can't quite understand why this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, *yes*.

Differentiation is a real operator, in the sense that if $u$ and $v$ are real-valued, then $(u + iv)' = u' + i(v')$.

If $f = u + iv$ is a solution to a homogeneous linear ODE with real coefficients, say
$$
0 = [Lf](t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(t) f^{(k)}(t)
$$
with $a_{k}$ real, then linearity of the derivative gives $f^{(k)}(t) = u^{(k)}(t) + iv^{(k)}(t)$. Substituting,
\begin{align*}
  0 = [L(u + iv)](t)
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(t) [u^{(k)}(t) + iv^{(k)}(t)] \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(t) u^{(k)}(t) + i\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(t) v^{(k)}(t) \\
  &= [Lu](t) + i[Lv](t).
\end{align*}
Each sum is real-valued, so each sum is $0$, i.e., $Lu = 0$ and $Lv = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how this relates to my question. What is L here?

Comment: By "linear differential equation" I assume you mean a sum of the stated form. "$Lf$" is just a convenient notation, with $L$ viewed as a real linear differential operator applied to a function $f$, so that a "solution" is precisely a function that $L$ sends to $0$.