# Why must a separation constant either be real or complex, but not both when using separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

**Question**: *Why must a separation constant either be real or complex, but not both, when using separation of variables?*

My textbook claims you can replace a purely imaginary separation constant (bj) with a real and imaginary (a+bj) separation constant **after** you solved the PDE, but provides no motivation why we are allowed to do this

**Motivation**:
Using separation of variables, one gets the following:

$$ \frac{x''}{x} = const. = - \lambda^2 $$

Assuming a solution of

$$y = e^{rx} $$

One gets

$$r^2 + \lambda^2  = 0 => r^2 = - \lambda^2 => r = \pm \lambda (j)$$

Hence,

$$ y = c_1 e^{+ \lambda x j} + c_2 e^{- \lambda x j}$$

**But** my textbook says to make the following replacement for generalization

$$ \lambda j => \alpha + \lambda j $$

Thus,

$$ y = c_1 e^{+ ( \alpha + \lambda j ) x } + c_2 e^{- ( \alpha + \lambda j)  x } = c_1 e^{+ (\beta ) x } + c_2 e^{- ( \beta )  x } $$

**However**, I thought the solution to a real and complex separation constant would like

$$ y = c_1 e^{ ( a + b j ) x } + c_2 e^{ ( a - b j)  x }   $$

since the auxiliary roots  would be:

$$r_+ = a + b j$$

$$r_- = a - b j$$

Comment: What is the original problem at hand? There is probably some physical argument underlying this related to the original problem.

Comment: IIRC, real numbers _are_ complex, they just have zero imaginary part. <> The point here appears to be that [differentiation is a real operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115852/is-the-real-part-of-a-complex-solution-to-a-linear-differential-equation-always).

Comment: @CameronWilliams Have a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVXo7.png . Gamma is real AND complex in the next section( a + bj ), but they stick with this form  (i.e. 12.9c) and do not 'update' it to exp((a + bj)x) + exp((a - bj)x)! Andrew, what would be a consequence besides wanting real solutions only?

Comment: So in theory, $k_x$, $k_y$, and $\gamma$ can all be complex simply from the ODEs they correspond to. *However* I guess they want plane waves in $x$ and $y$, but $z$ is subject to the constraint that it vanishes at $-\infty$ or $+\infty$ (or rather one piece vanishes at one, the other at the other) which is achieved only if the real part in the exponent is nonzero. They seem to allow for damped plane wave behavior in $z$ in general. Hope that helps.

Comment: “My textbook” is rather useless information. If you tell us **which** book it is, then maybe someone who has access to that book will be able to give a more informed answer.

Comment: The constant itself, which you are calling $\lambda^2$ is always real for well-posed separation of variables problems. So, dealing with the complex $\lambda$ is an artifact of assuming the form of the constant is $\lambda^2$. The constant is real because all well-posed separation of variables problems are self-adjoint, which makes the spectral parameter real, which can be positive or negative.

Comment: @HansLundmark it's **Elements of Electromagnetics** (ISBN 0199321388). I am interested in learning more of the math part, rather than the physics part (which is why it's on math exchange!) I wish I could select all these answers as best answer. -- ED